# What's wrong with the google tensorflow documentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction

I was following the https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv docs & came to a really frustrating issue. In this tutorial, a model predicts Titanic survivors. The final prediction values of the tutorial in there were not good at all (or I think so).

- Predicted survival: -236.86%  | Actual outcome:  SURVIVED
- Predicted survival: -100.17%  | Actual outcome:  DIED
- Predicted survival: -238.74%  | Actual outcome:  DIED
- Predicted survival: 147.69%  | Actual outcome:  DIED
- Predicted survival: 12.94%  | Actual outcome:  SURVIVED

How come the model predicts 12.94% as SURVIVED & 147.69% as DIED? What's happening in here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the last `Dense` layer should have an activation function `sigmoid`, indicating that the result must be between 0 and 1. This is what we want because we are predicting a probability. Without this the output can take any positive or negative value, hence the weird values you can see.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
           preprocessing_layer,
           tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
           tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
           tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'),
])
```

When you run the code again with the sigmoid, the result is

> Predicted survival: 100.00%  | Actual outcome:  DIED
>
> Predicted survival: 17.95%  | Actual outcome:  SURVIVED
>
> Predicted survival: 99.80%  | Actual outcome:  DIED
>
> Predicted survival: 0.00%  | Actual outcome:  DIED
>
> Predicted survival: 10.65%  | Actual outcome:  DIED

This makes much more sense.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this stuff. So isn't this a bad model to predict the survivors?

Comment: it's not very good because if you look at the first result for example, the model thinks that the person had 100% chance of survival but the person died. Maybe the neural network hasn't been trained long enough, maybe it's not the optimal number of neurons or layers. Truth is on small datasets like Titanic, it's hard to train neural networks that can perform well, they usually need a lot of data to be very accuracy. Standard machine learning techniques such as decision trees/ ensembles of tree often outperform NN